# Booting drops to EFI shell but boots normally if exit'ed

Tags: windows-7, boot, uefi

(first post here... I'm normally on stackoverflow)
I'm booting an Intel ME 5788 board which uses EFI (a replacement for BIOS). On boot it drops out to the EFI Shell and the 'map' shows the drive as a blockdevice but there is no filesystem device mapped. If I just type 'exit' it boots normally to windows 7 and the configuration (using bcdedit.exe) looks fine.

I'm confused - surely if its not been able to map the blockdevice as a filesystem device it should not boot? I would like to be able to get the boot to proceed without my interaction - does anyone know how to do it? (Also there is no Boot Manager options available in the shell, i.e. autoboot, bcfg etc)

Answer (score 1):

### You are conflating the boot and system volumes.

Only the *system* volume, which will be a true EFI System Partition in this case, needs to have a filesystem protocol, which it undoubtedly has.  The *boot* volume isn't accessed until Microsoft's Boot Manager comes to loading and running the Windows NT 6.x loader, `winload` — for which Microsoft's Boot Manager (for better or for worse) uses its own built-in filesystem drivers, not the firmware access methods.  The firmware *only* needs to be able to load and run Microsoft's Boot Manager, which of course lives on your system volume.

That's not a motherboard number that Intel — or at least its WWW site — knows.  But for Intel's Server Boards, at least, the procedure for removing the EFI Shell the first boot option is uniform across many products, and is the reverse of making it the first boot option, which is documented by Intel:  Simply press the function key for bringing up the firmware configuration utility before the EFI firmware startup reaches its BDS phase, go to the Boot Order Menu, and move the EFI Shell from first place.

Of course, the EFI Shell will *always* come up first if the board is jumpered to come up in recovery mode.  I presume that you've not put your mainboard into recovery mode.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [What "boot" and "system" volumes are](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [The Windows NT 6 boot process](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-boot-process.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [The EFI boot process](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/efi-boot-process.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- Intel Corporation (2008). [Basic Instructions for Using EFI (Extensible Firmware Interface) for Server Configuration on Intel Server Boards and Intel Server Systems](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/efi_whitepaper.pdf).

Comment: @kinokijuf Perhaps you should refer to the [updated, actually standard, RFC 3986](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), which specifies: *> The rightmost domain label of a fully qualified domain name in DNS may be followed by a single "."*